# Turn on the flashlight in android Lollipop Programatically

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, flashlight

I have been trying to turn on Flashlight in android lollipop but the camera Api is deprecated and hence donot turn on the Flashlight. Has anyone tried doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet to turn on flash light:

```
mCam = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters p = mCam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
mCam.setParameters(p);
mPreviewTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
try {
   mCam.setPreviewTexture(mPreviewTexture);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // Ignore
}
mCam.startPreview();
```

It works on Android 5.0.x. Add below permission in manifest for camera usage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```